# how to explain this loop result in python?

Tags: python, loops

```
x=range(1,4)
y=range(1,4)


[(xi,yi) for xi in x for yi in y if xi is yi]
 #output
 # [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]

[(xi,yi) for xi in x if xi is yi for yi in y ]
 #output, I am confused about this one
 #[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Can any one explain why the second loop results like this?

I am quite confused about how multiple in-line loops work in Python.

Also, any tutorial on python in-line loops is favored

Comment: When you're reaching that level of complexity I would probably not use a list comp for that. A regular loop may be more readable. Also, you shouldn't be using `is` like that. `is` checks object equality, not value equality.

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare numbers.  Use `==`.

Comment: I see the answer. Here is the point, the second loop runs after the first one. yi is actually 3 in the local scope. If run them alone, the second one will raise an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second construct isn't valid code on its own:

```
In [1]: x=range(1,4)

In [2]: y=range(1,4)

In [3]: [(xi,yi) for xi in x if xi is yi for yi in y ]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/aix/<ipython console> in <module>()

NameError: name 'yi' is not defined
```

The `yi` in `xi is yi` isn't referring to the `yi` that comes after that. It's referring to a pre-existing variable called `yi` (at least that's what happens during the very first iteration).

The only reason the code worked for you was that you had previously run the first construct and that had left behind `yi` (set to `3`) in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the point, the second loop runs after the first one, when I operated this.

yi is actually 3 in the local scope.

If running them alone, the second one will raise an error.